# My coins were sent from my metamask wallet to another wallet without my consent

Tags: transactions, security

I just claimed tokens after a presale had ended from the token site to my metamask wallet. That transaction was successful. However, just one minute after that transaction took place, my coins were sent from my metamask to another wallet without my doing .  They were sent to this wallet   0xbca9cfd7599a71a1ddab5097f2b899747c9f7428

and this is my wallet in which they were taken from 0x7701726F64a01461748577D8c09da3ca14c2CE28

is there anything I can to do get my coins back?  or do I just accept this loss

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was triggered from your account (0x7701726F64a01461748577D8c09da3ca14c2CE28), meaning **someone else seems to have access to your account**. You may have connected your wallet to a malicious page, which stole your private key or something similar. If I were you I would not use this wallet anymore.